# How to get the path about battery information in sysfs?

Tags: android

Generally battery driver will write the information about battery to sysfs.
The question is what is the folder name that the application should read?
'/sys/class/power_supply' or something else?

Comment: what are you trying to do? if you need battery level in your app you can use BatteryManager...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to get battery current value and average current value to calculate the remaining time for battery.